# Spring cloud stream kafka multiple consumers. Is there way to configure deserializer for each consumer separately?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I am using sprig cloud stream with kafka binding. I have multiple consumers with different content type. Is there a way i can configure deserializer at consumer basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the message channel binder:

See the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-consumer-properties

> **configuration**

> Map with a key/value pair containing generic Kafka consumer properties. In addition to having Kafka consumer properties, other configuration properties can be passed here. For example some properties needed by the application such as spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.configuration.foo=bar. The bootstrap.servers property cannot be set here; use multi-binder support if you need to connect to multiple clusters.

So `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inputProcess.consumer.configuration.value.deserializer=...`.

For the streams binder:

See the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_inbound_deserialization

> ...

> If none of the above strategies worked, then the applications must provide the `Serde`s through configuration. This can be configured in two ways - binding or default.

> First the binder will look if a Serde is provided at the binding level. For e.g. if you have the following processor,

```java
@Bean
public BiFunction<KStream<CustomKey, AvroIn1>, KTable<CustomKey, AvroIn2>, KStream<CustomKey, AvroOutput>> process() {...}
```

then, you can provide a binding level Serde using the following:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.process-in-0.consumer.keySerde=CustomKeySerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.process-in-0.consumer.valueSerde=io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.process-in-1.consumer.keySerde=CustomKeySerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.process-in-1.consumer.valueSerde=io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde
```

Comment: This is not working for following configuration somehow spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inputProcess.consumer.keySerde=CustomKeySerde

Comment: I am not using kstreams actually

Comment: Sorry; I updated the answer for the equivalent for the message channel binder.

Comment: Thanks @gary-russell. This thing worked. Apologies for late response.